# How can I cancel a ColumnChanging event and have the bound control show the original value instead of the rejected change?

Tags: c#, data-binding, event-handling

I have a rather complicated form with several interchangeable sub-panel classes, each of which has several user controls of its own. One of the sub-panels has a checkbox that, depending on what options are selected in other sub-panels may not be allowed to uncheck.

Ideally I would handle this by making the checkbox readonly when it's not allowed to uncheck, but that would entail detecting any change that could *potentially* enable/disable the checkbox, calculating whether it should be enabled, and then telling the sub-panel to enable/disable the checkbox. It seems like it would be easier to detect an attempt to uncheck the checkbox, calculate whether the current state allows unchecking it, and then accept or reject the attempt.

The convention we're using is to attach an event handler to a page's data table's ColumnChanged or ColumnChanging event and then have that handler call appropriate helper methods based on which column changed. I put in the code below:

```
private void MyTable_ColumnChanging(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e) {
   ...
   if (e.Column == MyTrueFalseColumn) {
      CheckboxChanging(e);
   }
   ...
}

private void CheckboxChanging(DataColumnChangeEventArgs e) {
   if (!(bool)e.ProposedValue && MustRemainChecked())
     e.ProposedValue = true;
}
```

I also tried `e.Row.SetColumnError(e.Column, "error message")`, `e.Row.CancelEdit()`, and `e.Row.RejectChanges()` in place of `e.ProposedValue = true` and confirmed those lines executed, but the checkbox still unchecks without any indication anything happened behind the scenes. I also tried all 4 of those cancellation methods followed by `MyCheckBox.DataBindings[0].ReadValue()`, again with no success.

I've used breakpoints to step through and confirm that the proposed value is being set to true, but the checkbox still unchecks when the event is complete. What am I doing wrong?

Is the data column properly storing true but the checkbox doesn't update to reflect that? Is there something else I need to do to have the data column store the changed ProposedValue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by messing with the checkbox directly in the ColumnChanged event rather than the ColumnChanging event:

```
private void MyTable_ColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Column == MyTrueFalseColumn)
      CheckboxChanged(e);
}

private void CheckboxChanged(DataColumnChangeEventArgs e) {
   if (!(bool)e.ProposedValue && MustRemainChecked()) {
      MyCheckbox.Checked = true;
      MyCheckbox.DataBindings[0].WriteValue();
   }
}
```

If anyone has a solution that only messes with the associated DataTable I'd be happy to accept that.

Answer (score 0):

```
e.Row.CancelEdit();
```

This will cancel the proposed value from updating the the current row of data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).